# У меня проблемы с sscanf

Tags: c, ввод

Я хотел сделать через sscanf спарсить вот это: `mes-ndf` (У меня будут не предсказуемые размеры слов), и мне нужно получить два буквенных массива: `mes` и `ndf`, но когда я пытался создать так:

```
include <stdio.h>

int main() {
 char txt[] = "mes-ndf";
 char a[32];
 char b[32];
 sscanf(txt, "%s-%s", a, b);
 printf("%s and %s", a, b);
}
```

Я получаю вот это: `mes-ndf and p@`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объясните явно, что в первой строке может быть что угодно, кроме символа `-`:

```
int main() {
    char txt[] = "mes-ndf";
    char a[32];
    char b[32];
    sscanf(txt, "%[^-]-%s", a, b);
    printf("%s and %s", a, b);
}
```

Comment: Да, а что точнее делает `%[^-]` (У меня всегда была проблема с такими функциями, на всех языках)

Comment: Это то же самое, что `%s`, но только с указанием, какие символы могут входить в слово, а какие нет. Здесь сказано - что угодно, но не `-`. Подробнее, например, [тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).